# How to require a game controller on TVOS

Tags: controller, tvos

I'm working on a game for TVOS that is designed to work with a MFI Controller. I cannot seem to find anywhere in the documentation how to mark the app (in settings, plist, or in itunesconnect) to display in the store "this app requires a game controller".

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution:

If you are building your app with Xcode 8 and linking with the tvOS 10 SDK, then here's how to require a game controller:

- Go to the "Capabilities" tab in Xcode and turn on the "Game Controllers" switch.
- Check the box for "Extended Gamepad". That's saying you support a game controller.
- Un-check (or leave blank) the box for "Micro Gamepad". That's saying you don't support the Siri Remote.

Source: [apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51490)